# How to cross check a technical skill (tag) with stackexchange api?

Tags: java, rest, tags, google-custom-search, stackexchange-api

I'm having some custom keywords/tags (technical keywords which are dynamically generated by a Machine Learning module). Example: MVC, aws, etc...
So what I need is to check whether that particular tag exists in stack exchange API.
Through following REST route, I'm able to get the tags but need to change the query string parameter 'page' manually.

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow&page=

Without that by calling an API or similar, is it possible to check whether my custom keyword is technical or not? It doesn't have to be StackExchange but something similar is also will be helpful. I tried https://developers.google.com/custom-search/ also but I'm having problems with finalizing the approach. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with [stack exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/), I found the following REST route which is useful.

[https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/{tags}/related?site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/unit-testing/related?site=stackoverflow)

Now I'm able to send a custom tag and get a list of related tags to that specific word. Since stackoverflow contains tech skill words, I was able to accomplish my task successfully from this.

Hope this would be helpful for someone who's having the same problem.